# What could be the source of capacitive coupling in these SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, grounding, capacitance

I have bought two of [these](https://www.americanas.com.br/produto/10584252/fonte-universal-para-notebook-carregador-knup-505a) cheap laptop power supplies for an audio amplifier I was building.

They work, but with a serious problem: They give mild to strong shocks to anybody touching the ground (or any of the AC mains) and touching the DC output.

I can easily stop that by grounding one of the terminals of the DC output, but they shouldn't need grounding and there isn't even a pin for the ground. There is no conductive path between the primary and secondary windings of the transformer and the capacitive coupling should be minimal.

I tested each power source for conductance between the AC inputs and the DC outputs, and got nothing. Not even in the 10^7 ohm scale.

I also tested applying 80 V DC between the inputs and the outputs to see if any current flowed. Nothing again.

But, when applying 127 V AC (60 Hz), a ~13 mA current flowed between the input and the output of the power source.

Calculating the capacitance, I found that each power source had a ~ 270 nF capacitance between the inputs and the outputs.

This is outrageously high. I measured several transformers I have (LF and HF) and none goes over 1 nF.

What could be the source of all this capacitance?

Thanks!

Comment: *They give mild to strong shocks to anybody touching the ground (or any of the AC mains)* As I read it, it is quite obvious: *touching … any of the AC mains* gives a shock. I guess you mean something else... Next, you applied 80 Vdc between the inputs and the outputs: did you short both inputs and short both outputs? And how did you apply the 127 Vac? The same way as the 80 Vdc?

Comment: One answer to [Got shocked by a native dell laptop charger...](https://superuser.com/a/1033997/272824) shows a capacitor in the PSU which can do that.

Comment: @Huisman I said touching [the ground or a main] and [the DC output]. A main alone won't shock you if you're not touching the ground, and there shouldn't be any path to the ground through the DC output. About measuring current between the outputs and inputs, it made no difference. Either shorting the inptus and the outputs or using one terminal of the input and another from the output gave the same exact results.

Comment: Return them as dangerous and faulty, and buy better power supplies.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That one is 2.2 nF, but a > 200 nF capacitance? That would be insanity. The shock was kinda strong using both my power supplies together (once the capacitances are in parallel no matter how I connect the DC outputs), and the current would be nearly the double if it was being used in 220 V.  Not only strong enough to kill someone with heart problems, it certainly would trigger an ELCB.

Comment: @user2934303 You're right. Leakage current should in no way exceed 3.5 mA. But I think you're question is not answerable as we can only do educated **guesses**. Unless you find the schematics of that SMPS or you tear it down...

Comment: @user2934303 How did you measure the 13mA leakage current? Can you try again with a proper leakage current measurement network, or even a makeshift one (1kohm resistor in parallel with 100nF capacitor, connected from PSU negative output to mains protective earth ground)? How much AC RMS voltage do you get over the 1kohm resistor? I also am stumped about this, but hey, it's cheap and chinese so not up to safety standards here. I wonder if it is really meant to have a grounded mains plug but just replaced with two prong plug. I also recommend to dissect it for our safety, it is useless as it is.